# Puzzle -- Does transformation from multiplicative random walk to additive change its properties?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Suppose we have the following stochastic process:

$$x_t=(1+\gamma)x_t, \  \ \ with \ \ 1/2 \ \ probability$$
$$x_t=(1-\gamma)x_t, \  \ \ with \ \ 1/2 \ \ probability$$

where $\gamma$ is some constant from $(0,1)$. In other words, the above stochastic process is a multiplicative random walk.

From the definition, we have:

$$\Delta x_t=\gamma x_t, \  \ \ with \ \ 1/2 \ \ probability$$
$$\Delta x_t=-\gamma x_t, \  \ \ with \ \ 1/2 \ \ probability$$

Therefore, the expected change of $x_t$ process for $[t, t+1]$ time interval is given by:

$$E [\Delta x_t]=1/2 \times [+\gamma x_t- \gamma x_t]=0.$$

Now, let's transform the multiplicative random walk into an additive random walk by taking $log$ of both sides:

$$log(x_t)=log(1+\gamma)+log(x_t), \  \ \ with \ \ 1/2 \ \ probability$$
$$log(x_t)=log(1-\gamma)+log(x_t), \  \ \ with \ \ 1/2 \ \ probability$$

From here the expected change in $log(x_t)$ is given by

$$E[\Delta log (x_t)]=1/2 \times [log(1+\gamma)+log(1-\gamma)]= 1/2 \times log (1-\gamma^2) \neq0$$

**Question:** How to explain inconsistence between the results, i.e. $E \Delta x_t=0$, but $E[\Delta log (x_t)] \neq 0$?

Comment: $\log$ is not a linear function but instead strictly concave.  So this is what you would expect to happen, related to Jensen's inequality

Comment: So what conclusion we can make from both calculations? From the first calculation, we can say that $x_t$ process in the long-run does not deviate from its initial value, $x_0$. However, the second calculation says that $log(x_t)$ proecess decreases over time. This is not a contradiction?

Comment: It is certainly not a contradiction, and to some people it is not even a surprise.  If you increase a number by $20\%$ and then reduce the bigger number by $20\%$, you end up $4\%$ down compared with where you started even though $20\%-20\%=0\%$

Comment: My question is slightly different. Suppose we have the process: $x_t=x_t+0.01 \times \gamma \times x_t$, where $\gamma$ attains either $-1$ or $+1$ with $1/2$ probabilities. The expected change $E (\Delta x_t)=0$ for each time-step, but in the long-term the process converges to $0$. This is not surprising if expected change for each time-step is still $0$?

Comment: No it is not surprising.  Take an extreme example where $\gamma=1=100\%$ so each turn doubles the amount or wipes it out completely.  After $n$ turns you either have $2^n$ with probability $2^{-n}$ or have $0$ with probability $1-2^{-n}$ and so the expected amount always remains $1$; but as $n$ increases the probability you have $0$ goes quickly towards $1$.  A smaller $\gamma$ behaves similarly: the probability you have less than any given small number increases towards $1$ as $n$ increases, though does so more slowly

Comment: I see, thank you. But for another process: $x_t=x_t+\gamma \times c$, where $\gamma$ takes either $-1$ or $1$ with probabilities $1/2$, and $c$ some constant, let's say $0.01$,  and $x_0=1$, then it is not clear that in the long-term the process will converge to 0. Then why for previous example it converges to 0? The reason is "proportionality" propoerty (change in process is proportional to current value, i.e. $\Delta x_t = \gamma \times x_t$)?

Comment: In you new case there is an issue of what happens if $x_t$ hits zero or less (if you then stop and otherwise never stop, then there is probability $1$ you will eventually have $0$ or less, but the expected time until this happens is infinite).  But this is a different process, being additive rather than multiplicative

Comment: Let's sat if the process hits 0, then we stop. So with probability 1 it will hit 0, why?

Comment: Let's say the process if hits $0$ we stop, also if it hits $2$ we also stop. So, in this case, for many iteration, what will happen eventually? It will converge to $0$ or to $2$?

Comment: It happens because a fair 1-D random walk is recurrent, and eventually you expect to visit any possible value.  The phenomenon is call the [gambler's ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin).  If you start at $a$ and stop at $0$ or $b$ then the probability of stopping at all is $1$ and the probability of stopping at $0$ is $\frac{b-a}{b}$, which tends to $1$ if $a$ is held constant while $b$ increases without limit

Comment: I see, thank you very much!!